# Sql Server MAX of sum(Amount)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which I have Payment details made by client. Columns are given below:

```
ID, ClientID, Amount
```

Now I want to find 5 maximum sum of amount group by client id.

I have found `DENSE_RANK()` but its not working for me as I want to find **sum of amount**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH totalSum
AS
(
    SELECT  ClientID, SUM(Amount) totalAmount
    FROM    tableName
    GROUP   BY ClientID
)
SELECT ClientID, totalAmount
FROM
    (
        SELECT  ClientID, totalAmount,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY totalAmount DESC) rn
        FROM    totalSum
    ) s
WHERE   rn <= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    ClientID,
    Amount
FROM
    PaymentDetails
GROUP BY
    ID
HAVING
   Amount = SUM(Amount)
```

Comment: This does not get the max 5 as the OP is seeking

Answer (score 0):

Please Try:

```
SELECT 
    ClientID, 
SUM(Amount) Amount 
FROM(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY Amount DESC) DR, 
        ClientID, 
        Amount 
    FROM YourTable
)x WHERE x.DR<=5
GROUP BY ClientID
ORDER BY ClientID
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? (not sure I understand your problem)
If you want the TOP 5 totals, this is it.
The query for finding the `SUM()` of the `TOP 5` Amounts per Client is different.

```
;WITH OrderingCTE AS
(
    SELECT   ID
            ,ClientID
            ,Amount = SUM(Amount)
            ,rNum   = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY SUM(Amount) DESC)
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY ID
            ,ClientID
)
SELECT *
FROM OrderingCTE
WHERE rNum <=5
```